# WLAN/LAN Profil Tool (with IP-Address configuration)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, switch, profile

Anyone know a good free tool for Vista/Windows 7 to manage WLAN/LAN-Profiles with the possibility to change the IP settings in each profile.

Answer (score 5):

**[IP Organizer 2](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/iporganizer.html)** does what it says on the tin.

[image]

the website is in Turkish, here's the [download link](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/dosyalar/IP_Organizer2.exe).

*IP Organizer is freeware.*

here's another one:

**[NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm)** allows you to quickly switch between pre-configured network settings.

[image]

*NetSetMan is free for personal use.*

Comment: +1 I'd upvote this more if I could...